The declared program id does not match the actual program id
I want to verify program on devnet and follow with the verified tutorial(https://solana.com/developers/guides/advanced/verified-builds#what-are-verified-builds) but get error when execute command solana-verify verify-from-repo -u https://devnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=f84a6f24-1feb-4290-bc2f-4fc95cf5e7f0 --program-id  7ZigWsEmK5JAW2mgKP19yRhcwt3gTpFMfkttXG7Hj9MF https://github.com/orbitlen/solana-contract
The program can normally be searched on solscan(https://solscan.io/account/7ZigWsEmK5JAW2mgKP19yRhcwt3gTpFMfkttXG7Hj9MF?cluster=devnet)
Console:
Finished building program
Program Solana version: v1.18.26
Docker image Solana version: v1.18.26
13eb80ccdb8f9f8a39eedbc1b09614810cb863a20ca1a887a265f1419ad2bd3f
Executable file found at path: "/tmp/solana-verify/44ce27cd-bc81-4493-9313-6d7992fa89b6/solana-contract//target/deploy/orbit_len.so"
Fetching on-chain program data for program ID: 7ZigWsEmK5JAW2mgKP19yRhcwt3gTpFMfkttXG7Hj9MF
Executable Program Hash from repo: 13eb80ccdb8f9f8a39eedbc1b09614810cb863a20ca1a887a265f1419ad2bd3f
On-chain Program Hash: 13eb80ccdb8f9f8a39eedbc1b09614810cb863a20ca1a887a265f1419ad2bd3f
Program hash matches ✅
Do you want to upload the program verification to the Solana Blockchain? (y/n) y
Uploading the program verification params to the Solana blockchain...
Using connection url: https://devnet.helius-rpc.com/?api-key=f84a6f24-1feb-4290-bc2f-4fc95cf5e7f0
Error { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x1004", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(0, Custom(4100))), logs: Some(["Program verifycLy8mB96wd9wqq3WDXQwM4oU6r42Th37Db9fC invoke [1]", "Program log: AnchorError occurred. Error Code: DeclaredProgramIdMismatch. Error Number: 4100. Error Message: The declared program id does not match the actual program id.", "Program verifycLy8mB96wd9wqq3WDXQwM4oU6r42Th37Db9fC consumed 2934 of 200000 compute units", "Program verifycLy8mB96wd9wqq3WDXQwM4oU6r42Th37Db9fC failed: custom program error: 0x1004"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(2934), return_data: None, inner_instructions: None }) }) }
Error uploading program: Err(Failed to send transaction to the network.)


Can you run command anchor keys list in your project directory and see if the programId matches with the one mentioned in declare_id

I have been checking this item.

This might have been you on GitHub in this issue: https://github.com/Ellipsis-Labs/solana-verifiable-build/issues/110
But for posterity, uploading program verification on-chain only works on mainnet-beta.
